# Symfony Form Constraints connection beetwen fields

Tags: php, symfony

I have question about constraints,

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

I have entity with  multiple checkboxes (boolean type) .

Now i need some non-standard logic  here  like:

- if checkbox A is checked then checkbox B must be checked too.
- if checkboxes A,B,C  are checked  then checkbox D must be checked too

And  now the question is  :

**Am i able to make logic  like this with constraints** (if yes  - it would be grat if someone can provide example)  ?  or only way is to move this logic to controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your logic is specific, you have to do some specific code to validate it.

Symfony gives you 3 tools to do it:

[The Callback Constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) which is a custom php function (see @Yoshi answer's)

[The Expression Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html) which is a custom expression parsed. Example:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "'1' in this.getCheckboxValues() and !('3' in this.getCheckboxValues())",
 * )
 */
```

Or your own  [custom constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution would be to use a [callback contraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html):

Something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

class Entity
{
    private $checkbox_a = false;
    private $checkbox_b = false;
    private $checkbox_c = false;
    private $checkbox_d = false;

    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     *
     * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
     * @param mixed                     $payload
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
    {
        if ($this->checkbox_a && !$this->checkbox_b) {
            $context->buildViolation('Must be checked because of checkbox_a!')
                ->atPath('checkbox_b')
                ->addViolation();
        }

        if ($this->checkbox_a && $this->checkbox_b && $this->checkbox_c && !$this->checkbox_d) {
            $context->buildViolation('Must be checked because of all others are checked!')
                ->atPath('checkbox_d')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```